# Using Build-Tools (Alex) with Stack and GHCjs

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghcjs

I depend on a package that needs alex to build, i also need ghcjs.

When i try to run `stack ghci`:

```
language-java-0.2.8: configure (lib)

Error:
--  While building package language-java-0.2.8 using:
      <long command>
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /Users/LeanderK/Documents/Haskell/exemplator-java_parser/.stack-work/logs/language-java-0.2.8.log

Configuring language-java-0.2.8...
Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1: The program
'alex' version >=3.1.3 is required but it could not be found.

Warning: Build failed, but optimistically launching GHCi anyway
The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -threaded
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: exemplator-client
Using main module: 1. Package `exemplator-client' component exe:exemplator-client-exe with main-is file:         ..../app/Main.hs
Progress: 1/2<command line>: cannot satisfy -package language-java-0.2.8
(use -v for more information)
```

I've tried: `stack build alex` (just returns, don't have any output. Might work), `stack install alex` (doesn't work).

Output of `stack install alex`

```
Couldn't find executable alex in directory .../.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-7.19/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/bin/
```

For reference: [This](https://github.com/zyla/language-java/blob/2369019638881d8ea4c564cd1f3eb3b41149769b/language-java.cabal) is the cabal file of the dependency, unfortunately only found on github. [This](https://gist.github.com/LeanderK/abe9a3854ada35570aca5188f1711a84) is my stack and my [cabal](https://gist.github.com/LeanderK/d132905d57723183b1130d8e85dccf7e) file. There is also a [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6ew2kq/need_help_with_stack_setup/) discussion that didn't go anywhere.

Comment: Does `cabal install alex` in `~` work?

Comment: Doesn't cabal automatically install into `~/.cabal/bin`? `cabal install alex` does work, but doesn't change the situation with stack. Is there a way to make stack aware of cabal-installed alex?

Comment: cabal installs into a sandbox by default if one is present, which is why I added that. Don’t know about stack though, sorry.

Comment: ok, i installed alex globally via cabal without any sandbox and it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: I think you need to add `build-tools: alex` to your library in the cabal file.